# Syncing Time on a Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've tried doing the NTP, but this pi travels from various places at various times a month and doesn't always have the proper access for NTP. Is there a way I can have it sync with Colorado's atomic clock during its booting sequence?

I currently running Raspian OS on the 512 version of Model B

Answer (score 5):

There are three options by which you can sync your raspberry pi time.

**Solution 1:** you can use RTC or any hardware clock and you can sync your RPi time with the clock.

**Solution 2:** Use a GPS module and sync the time with that.This will not work properly until your get you GPS locked.

**Solution 3:** You can use NTP server to sync your Raspberry Pi time. At this case you need your RPi connected to Internet.

First install `ntp` to your Pi.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ntpdate
```

Then reconfigure your `tzdata` with your location and local time by typing

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Now you need to run this following commands to sync your RPi time with NTP server.

```
$ sudo service ntp stop
$ sudo ntpdate -s time.nist.gov
$ sudo service ntp start`
```

If you want to sync your time with web on start/reboot, you have to add it in your cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck on this for a while. Was able to sync to the NTP server but was always 9 hours ahead. Fixed it by forcing a timezone change to Pacific.

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I have understand the question correctly – if syncing manually to the internet time whenever online and then let the local RTC do its job when offline is good enough, then you should use an external RTC module, like [this one](http://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/17209332-adding-a-real-time-clock-to-your-raspberry-pi) (or [this one](https://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/)) and follow the instructions on how to configure the Linux to get the time locally instead from internet. On the adafruit's 'Set RTC Time' page it says  *"Once the time is correct* [i.e. from the internet] *(...), run sudo hwclock -w to write the system time to the RTC"*, so I assume this command can be used later at anytime to sync again the local clock with the defined NTP clock (but cannot check this for myself, as I don't have a hardware RTC yet).

As for the timezone, if using Raspbian this can be set via `sudo raspi-config` > `Internationalisation Options` (when in command line mode) or via Menu > Preferences > Raspberry Pi Configuration > Localisation (when in desktop mode).